# Finding records that overlap a range in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So, I have an `Event` model that has a `starts_at` and a `ends_at` column and I want to find events that take place in a range of dates.

I've come up with this `named_scope` (`range` is typically a month):

```
named_scope :in_range, lambda { |range|
  {:conditions => [
    'starts_at BETWEEN ? AND ? OR ends_at BETWEEN ? AND ?',
    range.first, range.last, range.first, range.last]} }
```

Which works as expected.

**But** if an event starts the month before **and** ends the month after the range it won't show. Is there any way to find those events in a proper way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are four cases:

```
     Start    End
1.      |-----|
2.  |------|
3.  |-------------|
4.         |------|
```

Your named_scope only gets cases 1,2 and 4. So you just need need to add:

```
named_scope :in_range, lambda { |range|
  {:conditions => [
     '(starts_at BETWEEN ? AND ? OR ends_at BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (starts_at <= ? AND ends_at >= ?)',
     range.first, range.last, range.first, range.last, range.first, range.last
   ]}
}
```

Comment: That's great! Nice diagram too :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess an event overlaps if it begins before the range ends *and* ends after the range begins. :)

So:

```
{:conditions => ['? < ends_at AND ? > starts_at', range.first, range.last]}
```