# rails custom validation not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I want to run validation that would return an error message if a booking already exist.

**LATEST UPDATE**

> It works but it leads me to a new question with updated working code:
>   [Rails code readability for my validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551261/rails-code-readability-for-my-validation)

**STATUS UPDATE**

> It triggers validation roll_back when the room already has a Booking
>   (already a start) BUT now I want to figure out a code so that it only
>   roll_back when dates overlaps and not just because there is a booking.

Here is my schema:

```
  create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.datetime "end_date"
    t.integer  "length"
    t.integer  "room_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "type_room"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

My associations in addition to the booking model:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bookings
end
```

Thank you everybody for your help in advance. Antoine

**UPDATED CONTROLLER**

```
  def create_book_now
  @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])

#Save booking in DB if model validation are OK
booking = @room.bookings.build(booking_params)

if booking.save
  booking.update(end_date: booking.start_date + booking.length.days)
  flash[:notice] = "Booking done"
  redirect_to root_path
else
  flash[:error] =  booking.errors.full_messages.first if booking.errors.any?
  redirect_to room_book_now_path(@room.id)
end

  end
```

**UPDATED MODEL**

```
def dates_are_available
    room = Room.find(self.room_id)
    # if Room.find(self.room_id).bookings.exists?
    #    self.errors.add(:base, 'Date already taken')
    # end
    conditions = []
    conditions << '(start_date >= :new_start_date AND end_date >= :new_end_date)'
    conditions << '(start_date >= :new_start_date AND end_date <= :new_end_date)'
    conditions << '(end_date BETWEEN :new_start_date AND :new_end_date)'
    conditions << '(start_date <= :new_start_date AND end_date >= :new_end_date)'
    if room.bookings.where(conditions.join(' OR '), new_start_date: self.start_date, new_end_date: self.end_date).exists?
        self.errors.add(:base, 'Date already taken')
        return false
    end
end
```

Now this validation work but instead of throwing an error it decide to not record the end_date that is recorded in the controller

Comment: Do you mean that your validation is not getting executed? How did you know this?

Comment: First things first, I wouldn't handle the redirect in the model itself... That should be in the controller. Regardless, can you add `logger.debug 'in validation'` to see if your validation is getting called?

Comment: I know it is not getting executed because the redirect does not happen and I see that the record is saved in the DB. On purpose I try to create a record that should get the validation to work.

Comment: I must do something wrong with my controller ? I am supposed to tell the controller that it must ran validation when a Booking is created ?

Comment: your if statement for validate_existing_dates might not be working correctly. Add a binding.pry after the if statement and see if it actually triggers correctly.

Comment: I have updated model and controller as they seem very messy to me. Now Its clearer and maybe it will help you to help me understanding how can I run validation for my booking in the model so that if booking for a room already exists with requested date it is not saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MrYoshiji contribution I added to his code the `room_id` info and more SQL to cover all possible date overlaps. Here is what worked for me:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :room

    validates :length, :presence => true

    validate :dates_are_available

    def dates_are_available
        room = Room.find(self.room_id)
        conditions = []
        conditions << '(start_date >= :new_start_date AND end_date >= :new_end_date)'
        conditions << '(start_date >= :new_start_date AND end_date <= :new_end_date)'
        conditions << '(end_date BETWEEN :new_start_date AND :new_end_date)'
        conditions << '(start_date <= :new_start_date AND end_date >= :new_end_date)'
        if room.bookings.where(conditions.join(' OR '), new_start_date: self.start_date, new_end_date: self.end_date).exists?
            self.errors.add(:base, 'Date already taken')
            return false
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I tried this for one of my requirement. It works well, but not helping me in 2 scenarios. First-> Does not allow me to save record if the new_start_date and new_end_date is lesser than the start_date and end_date in any record existing in the DB. And Second -> if I try to update instead of create, then also it does not allow me to save the same record. Don't know if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of `DateBooking` model is just to test if you are not create a `Booking` with a `start_date` + `length` combination that is not overlapping an already existing `Booking`, then you don't need this `DateBooking` model:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :dates_are_available

  def dates_are_available
    conditions = []
    conditions << '(start_date BETWEEN :new_start_date AND :new_end_date)' # the new range contains an already existing start_date
    conditions << '(end_date BETWEEN :new_start_date AND :new_end_date)' # the new range contains an already existing end_date
    conditions << '(start_date <= :new_start_date AND end_date >= :new_end_date)' # the new range contains an already existing range start_date..end_date
    if Booking.where(conditions.join(' OR '), new_start_date: self.start_date, new_end_date: self.end_date).exists?
      self.errors.add(:base, 'Date already taken')
    end
  end
```

Edit, new try:

```
  def dates_are_available
    conditions = []
    conditions << '(end_date BETWEEN :new_start_date AND :new_end_date)'
    conditions << '(start_date <= :new_start_date AND end_date >= :new_end_date)'
    if Booking.where(conditions.join(' OR '), new_start_date: self.start_date, new_end_date: self.end_date).exists?
      self.errors.add(:base, 'Date already taken')
      return false
    end
  end
```

Comment: I tried your code, I just pasted it in my model and it does not work. The Booking is saved in the DB and it completely ignored the validation

Comment: In my controller I am now trying to verify if its valid before saving it but I end up with the same problem

Comment: You are right I do not need a DateBooking model to just verify dates. I have updated my controller and cleaned it.

Comment: Now I am trying to figure out how to make your code work

Comment: I manage to trigger validation roll back when the room already has a Booking (cool) BUT now I want to figure out a code so that it only roll back when dates overlaps and not just because there is a booking.

Comment: @Antoine then use my code which test this overlapping issue

Comment: I love your code but It does not work, I can not figure why!  I am convinced your code should be my solution. I do not understand but with your code my Booking does not record the end_date attribute which is start_date + length and its calculated in my controler

Comment: Can you confirm that ruby does go into the `dates_are_available` method? (put a `raiser "here"` and save a Booking record, it should raise an error "here") ; If yes, then I might have not covered every possibilities in my SQL conditions.

Comment: what do you mean a "raiser" ? what should I write in my method to raise an eroor

Comment: litterally write `raiser "here"` in the `dates_are_available` method. It will throw an error, and the message of the error will be `"here"`. It pretty usefull to raise errors like this when you are suspecting a piece of code to not be executed.

Comment: I get: undefined method `raiser' for #<Booking:0x007feec5c5d8c8>

Comment: I wrote raiser "here" as the first line to be executed in the dates_are_available method

Comment: Well it is not what we wanted to achieve but at least we know that ruby is trying to execute the code inside `dates_are_available` (we should have used `raise StandardError` instead). This means my SQL conditions are not finding a record having a date-range in conflict with the one we are creating.

Comment: So I get the here message like you said, its good then what next :-) ?

Comment: So now upon saving a new booking we know that the validation code is run properly. now what is wrong with that code.

Comment: I noticed that somehow your code work but instead of throwing an error it decide to not save end_date when a booking is overlapping

Comment: look at this answer for the SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682638/finding-records-that-overlap-a-range-in-rails in my case number 2 is not working but 1,3,4 is

Comment: I forgot to `return false` if we find already existing booking. Have you tried my piece of code in my latest edit?

Comment: I just updated my model with a new dates_are_available method (inspired by your new edit and I added SQL + room_id), I have run all the different case scenario and it works, the only problem is that instead of throwing an error the validation save the booking but with no end_date
Maybe my controller is missing something

Comment: I posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551261/rails-code-readability-for-my-validation