# Rails code readability for my validation

Tags: sql, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, code-readability

The code works fine in detecting overlapping dates to not save a Booking if it already exist for a given Room. However, I had to twist my code to make it work because validation would make the `update` in my controller not valid instead of the `save`. So I want to know what is wrong with my code as normally the not valid should apply to the save and not the update.

In fact, to tell me that a booking cannot be saved instead of throwing an error, it just did not update the booking.end_date in my contoller while it should raise an error when it save and not when I try to update it:

I have a controller that create a new booking for a room (this is what I want to improve):

```
  def create_book_now
    @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
    booking = @room.bookings.build(booking_params)

    if booking.save  #I want to not save if model validation are not OK
      if @room.bookings.last.update(end_date: booking.start_date + booking.length.days) # I have to check if this is true for my validation to work, I am sure it is not normal
        flash[:notice] = "Booking done"
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        flash[:error] =  "booking.errors.full_messages.first if booking.errors.any?"
        redirect_to room_book_now_path(@room.id)
      end
    else
      flash[:error] =  booking.errors.full_messages.first if booking.errors.any?
      redirect_to room_book_now_path(@room.id)
    end
  end
```

The new booking go through validation to make sure no booking with overlapping date has been made:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :room

    validates :length, :presence => true

    validate :dates_are_available

    def dates_are_available
        room = Room.find(self.room_id)
        # if Room.find(self.room_id).bookings.exists?
        #    self.errors.add(:base, 'Date already taken')
        # end
        conditions = []
        conditions << '(start_date >= :new_start_date AND end_date >= :new_end_date)'
        conditions << '(start_date >= :new_start_date AND end_date <= :new_end_date)'
        conditions << '(end_date BETWEEN :new_start_date AND :new_end_date)'
        conditions << '(start_date <= :new_start_date AND end_date >= :new_end_date)'
        if room.bookings.where(conditions.join(' OR '), new_start_date: self.start_date, new_end_date: self.end_date).exists?
            self.errors.add(:base, 'Date already taken')
            return false
        end
    end
end
```

So my question is how to make my code in my controller better so that the validation will work when Booking is saved and not when it is updated

Comment: Do you mean that you only want the validations to run when the record is first created and saved to disc, but not on subsequent updates?

Comment: What I want is inside my controller, not to have to verify if update == true to proceed. the problem is that my validation still save a booking with a end_date of nil instead of throwing an error so in my controller I have to verify  if  `@room.bookings.last.update (true?)` to not have this problem. My validation make the update == false while I think it should be the save that should be == false. I want to understand why its not happening like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that, check all bookings that you assing to your room before save, and one by one check the condition.

```
def dates_are_available
    room.bookings.each do |b|
        if bookings.start_date
            self.errors.add(:base, 'Date already taken')
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: No the problem is not in the validation code. And your code does not verify all possible date overlap.